# Database Design: Line Items & Additional Items

Tags: vb.net, database-design, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am looking for a solution or to be told it simply is not possible/good practice.

I currently have a database whereby I can create new orders and select from a lookup table of products that I offer. This works great for the most part but i would also like to be able to add random miscellaneous items to the order. For instance one invoice may read "End of Tenancy Clean" and the listed product but then have also an entry for "2x Lightbulb" or something to that effect.

I have tried creating another lookup table for these items but the problem is i don't want to have to pre-define every conceivable item before I can make orders. I would much prefer to be able to simply type in the Item and price when it is needed.

Is there any database design or workaround that can achieve this? Any help is greatly appreciated. FYI I am using Lightswitch 2012 if that helps.

Comment: after one user enters a misc. item, should it also be available to other users?

Comment: Not necessarily, the misc item could be absolutely anything and even if it was a similar item could have a different price...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option I've seen in the past is a record in your normal items table labeled something like "Additional Service", and the application code will recognize this item and also require you to enter or edit a description to print with the invoice.

Comment: I did consider this but i was concerned of the following:  the user will have access to a screen where the existing products will be editable, if this "additional service" field was deleted from the list  would this mess up my written code? (apologies of this seems like a really stupid question, im just getting to grips with some concepts)

Answer (score 0):

In the ERP system which we have at work, there is a flag in the parts table which allows one to change the description of the part in orders; in other words, one lists the part number in the order and then changes the description. This one off description is stored in a special table (called NONSTANDARD) which basically has two fields - an id field and the description. There is a field in the 'orderlines' table which stores the id of the record in the special table. Normally the value of this field will be 0, which means that the normal description of the part be displayed, but if it's greater than 0, then the description is taken from the appropriate row in the nonstandard table.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

[image]

*(only key attributes included, for brevity)*